# Remote Debugger, step into assembly code

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wcf, remote-debugging

I am using the remote debugger in Visual Studio to do some WCF debugging.  All of that is working great, but while attached to the remote process, I cannot step into code that is defined in an external assembly.  Said assembly is built by me, and the symbol files are in the proper location on the service side.  If I try to step into the code, it just skips over and goes on its merry way.  What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, here it is, in all of my bone-headed wisdom, I just rebuilt the offending assembly as 'Debug' and now everything works perfectly.  Go me.  :^P

Comment: Sometimes talking about your problems helps most :) You can simply delete the question.

Comment: Yeah, I'm just gonna leave it here because someone else might be making the same silly mistake.  It is good to be reminded once in a while too.